# How to set dynamic variable in postman

Tags: variables, postman, access-token

I am working on set of API development which needs authorization so in headers I have to include key as `Authorization` and value as `Bearer <access_token>` like below:

[image]

I have another authorization api which I call and in return it gives me below data which has token value:

```
{
    "data": {
        "access_token": "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.kEoNTY84S2sxjAlLGmfJzKYJ_20m9tOR22l3XFdrZVOR4Kv3X1ThZRvr-WckfVN0PeyQ_IIMdY7cf231MRfdMd8dTe0HdSobrBWuFel7gmdmstAWPeNLj5hIM2mQueNuyOa3PucR9qfOr0yQ-FA7I4F2UjFLN7WfU0NhP0hnI3Qg4mnnq1xc727kvZWC9KzbEszVpEnVtewLxKgWIIwRl_NsG6ghIO0utc3aJsU8f7oULVtb99gUhLM-4v5YcAk2xZebRoVnsJYv4tfg8cZJasG9POv7akzdjD8tKhjF1hOGjcowY3E0AxdiC4wYU0S7fj2Mpx4HD1gV9hPneFTgaA",
        "expires_in": "3599",
        "expires_on": "1618296096",
        "ext_expires_in": "3599",
        "not_before": "1618292196",
        "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
        "token_type": "Bearer"
    },
    "msg": "",
    "status": true
}
```

It has `access_token` which I have to copy in all the other apis to authorize. This token expires every 60min so I have to copy paste the token again and again. Is there any way available through which I can define a dynamic variable in postman and assign it value of `access_token` so that whenever it expires, I simply query the authorization api and value of that dynamic variable is automatically refreshed. This will help in copy pasting the token again in all the other APIs.

EDIT:

I have set the token variable in getoauthtoken api

[image]

In another api, I have now used `{{token}}` but looks like its not able to find it

[image]

Comment: You should be able to just use `pm.environment.set('token', pm.response.json.data.access_token)` in the Tests tab. Once you have the variable saved, you can use `{{token}}` as the header value. If it expired l, make the token request again to set the new value everywhere.

Comment: It's one of the options in your image, just below the address bar, 3 along from the Headers that you have highlighted :D

Comment: @DannyDainton Did you mean that in my authroization api, in tests tab I will mention this and only use `{{token}}` in header of all the other APIs.?

Comment: For the request that returns that `access_token` in the response, add the script to the Tests tab. Once you run that request, it will get the `access_token` value and set it to the `token` variable. Then add the `{{token}}` syntax in the place where you are manually pasting the token value every 60 mins.

Comment: @DannyDainton Thanks. When I do this, I get an error which say check postman console for more details and this what the error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined`

Comment: My bad, should be `pm.response.json().data.access_token`

Comment: This worked but in another request in headers when I mention `{{token}}` it remains in red and the request also throws 500 error. I think its not able to find this variable `{{token}}`

Comment: You might need to update/edit your question to provide some visual clues about what you're seeing. I can't see what's in front of you :D

Comment: This is setting an _environment_ variable, do you have an environment created or selected, for it to store the value in? If not, you could just use the global scope instead - `pm.globals.set('token', pm.response.json().data.access_token`

Comment: It worked. If you can answer, I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use this in the Tests tab:

```
 pm.globals.set('token', pm.response.json.data.access_token)
```

Once you have the variable saved, you can use `{{token}}` as the header value.

If it expires, make the token request again to set the new value everywhere.

Alternatively, you could use something like this (you would need to modify the script for your context) to automatically refresh the token when it expires:

https://dannydainton.com/2018/09/10/postman-the-bearer-of-good-news/

Answer (score 2):

You can go the the Test tab. and copy/paste this code javascript code.

```
pm.environment.set('token', pm.response.json().token)
```

And after the saving the token value into the environment variable you can go to the `Authorization` **tab** and click on the **Type dropdown menu** and select `Bearer token` like in screenshoot.

[image]

And then place this into the token input `{{token}}`

[image]